# Ubuntu touchpad while typing

Tags: touchpad

I currently am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a lenovo laptop. No matter what I do (I have tried using dconf to enable the disable touchpad while typing), my touchpad still moves around while I am typing. Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Usually there's a keyboard combination that toggles the keypad. Is that good enough?

Comment: Specify what you have tried, i.e., what key did you change in dconf? What else did you try? DId you check the setting "Disable while typing" in Gnome Tweaks?

Comment: Hmm I think I found a fix. I had to use synclient. Before, I did check the disable while typing in Gnome Tweaks. That didn't work, so then I used something called Touchpad Indicator. That didn't work, and I also didn't find anything in syndaemon that helped. Eventually, I used modified TapButtons in synclient, and that finally fixed my problem.